# Update to an XML Column

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Trying to update an XML column for Sales Managers on our customers table on SQL.

Format of Column and name of it are like this:

```
<CustomColumnsCollection>
   <CustomColumn>
      <Name>ReceiveRebate</Name>
      <DataType>5</DataType>
      <Value>False</Value>
   </CustomColumn>
   <CustomColumn>
      <Name>Sales Manager</Name>
      <DataType>0</DataType>
      <Value>Ben Dover</Value>
   </CustomColumn>
   <CustomColumn>
      <Name>SurveyDate</Name>
      <DataType>1</DataType>
      <Value />
   </CustomColumn>
</CustomColumnsCollection>
```

I am trying to update the  Sales Manager value column, so Instead of Ben Dover it would  Gary Shaw for example.

So Far I have this:

```
UPDATE Customers
SET CustomColumns.modify('replace value of 
(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn[@Name=("Sales Manager ")]/Value/text())[1] with ("Gary Shaw")
')
WHERE CustomerID = 'aptcustomerid'
```

It runs successfully but It seemingly does nothing, any clues would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 ( 12.0.4100.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it.

(1) The *XPath* expression was off. There are no attributes in the XML. `<Name>` is an element.

(2) I added an SQL variable for flexibility to find a proper XML fragment.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, CustomColumns XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl ( CustomColumns) VALUES
(N'<CustomColumnsCollection>
   <CustomColumn>
      <Name>ReceiveRebate</Name>
      <DataType>5</DataType>
      <Value>False</Value>
   </CustomColumn>
   <CustomColumn>
      <Name>Sales Manager</Name>
      <DataType>0</DataType>
      <Value>Ben Dover</Value>
   </CustomColumn>
   <CustomColumn>
      <Name>SurveyDate</Name>
      <DataType>1</DataType>
      <Value />
   </CustomColumn>
</CustomColumnsCollection>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

DECLARE @nameElement VARCHAR(30) = 'Sales Manager';

UPDATE @tbl
SET CustomColumns.modify('replace value of 
(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn[Name=sql:variable("@nameElement")]/Value/text())[1] 
with ("Gary Shaw")
');
--WHERE CustomerID = 'aptcustomerid'

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```